# How to hide text fields while print the report using JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm developing report compatible with *pdf*, *xls* and *html*.
I need to hide a text field when print the report in *JasperReports*.
I've use the ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.key.{keyvalue}*** property to hide the text field while export the document in *pdf*.
I need the same while take print the report.

Comment: Are you talking about *Java* code? What is your current code for printing report?

Comment: How are you printing your report?

Comment: I'll print the exported document from browser.